# Dynamic htaccess, how to render dynamic page on another domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have one website, and I have 12 domains (which will be increased in future),

Right now, I'm using this .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

which is for example rendering my website on

```
http://www.main-domain.com
```

Now, I have so many groups in my website, which I need to have different domains, like I have

```
    http://www.main-domain.com/group1
    http://www.main-domain.com/group2
    http://www.main-domain.com/group3
    .....
    http://www.main-domain.com/group30
```

Now, what I want is to check from DB if this group1 has domain name stored then I want this:

```
http://www.main-domain.com/group1/all-other-pages
```

to render on

```
http://www.group1.com/all-other-pages
```

else if this group doesnt has domain name stored then it stays like this

```
http://www.main-domain.com/group1/all-other-pages
```

I need this checking stuff to be dynamic, as number of groups will be increased day by day and I'll be pushing complete domain name  (e.g: www.group20.net) to specific group in database at desired time.

Please Please help me with this rewriting thing, I dont know .htaccess at all.
I know this is possible! but dont know to do this :P

Comment: I think what you need is a php script to handle this dynamically. It would be much easier.

Comment: The PHP `header()` function will do what you need after you make the checks in your script http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php